# Sinon stub instance method declared in mapDispatchToProps

Tags: unit-testing, testing, react-redux, sinon, enzyme

New to testing and React Redux, so I may be conflating a few issues here. I will only present one example, but I have tried many different combinations of `mount()`, `shallow()`, `instance()`, `stub`, `spy` and more.

Given a component, where `setFooData()` updates redux state and `Foo.props.data`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => ({
    setFooData(fooId, data) {
        dispatch(Actions.setFooData(fooId, data));
    },
});

...

return (
        <div fooId={this.props.fooId}>
            <Foo {...fooProps}/>
        </div>
    );
```

I would like to write some tests around the conditions under which `setFooData()` is called, namely conditions in lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount()` and `componentWillReceiveProps()`.

Because `setFooData()` involves server calls and more, and because these tests merely concern the view layer and how the component renders as a result of `Foo.props.data` being set eventually by `setFooData()`, `setFooData()` seems like a good candidate for `stub`.

Therefore, Enzyme's `shallow()`, rather than `mount()`, seems appropriate, correct? In any case, when I try to `stub` `setFooData()`:

```
let wrapper = return shallow(<Foo {...props}/>);
let stub = sinon.stub(wrapper.instance(), 'setFooData');
```

I receive the error:

`Attempted to wrap undefined property setFooData as function`

Upon inspection, `wrapper.instance()` yields an object where `setFooData()` is indeed not defined, but according to other examples, I would think it should be.

Furthermore, `setFooData()` does exist on `wrapper.instance().selector.props`, and while `let stub = sinon.stub(wrapper.instance().selector.props, 'setFooData');` avoids the error, when I inspect the object `setFooData() =/= stub`, and the function is not called as per the test.

When I use `mount()` instead,

```
let wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><Foo {...props}/></Provider>);

let componentDidMountSpy = sinon.spy(Foo.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
let componentWillReceivePropsSpy = sinon.spy(Foo.prototype, 'componentWillReceiveProps');

expect(componentDidMountSpy.called).to.be.true;         //passes
expect(componentWillReceivePropsSpy.called).to.be.true; //passes
expect(stub.called).to.be.true;                         //fails
```

I receive a different error that appears related to the body of `setFooData()`, so `setFooData()` is called but the function is not actually stubbed to prevent its real body from being executed.

Thanks for any help to clarify my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're taking the hardest path. You should test your component in isolation, not the `connect`ed one. If you test the `connect`ed component you're making an integration test and double testing that `connect` indeed works. That's already tested in react-redux for you.

Instead, test your action creators by themselves in unit tests.
Then, export your component as named export without connecting and use the default export for the connect version.

That way you can simply import the pure-React version and pass anything you want as props, in order to make easy assertions afterwards.

If you need to specifically test that something happens in those lifecycle methods, you can call those methods from the `instance`:

```
const fakeActionCreator = sinon.spy()
const subject = mount(<MyComponent doSomething={ fakeActionCreator } />)
subject.instance().componentDidMount()
assert.equal(fakeActionCreator.callCount, 1)
```